# How to retrieve values from Dynamically created Textboxes using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

One of my form allows to add multiple elements using Jquery. Following HTML shows the demo content,

```
<form name="my-location-frm">
    <div class="address">
        <input type="text" name="house-name" value='house1'>
        <input type="text" name="street-no" value='street1'>
    </div>

    <div class="address">
        <input type="text" name="house-name" value='house2'>
        <input type="text" name="street-no" value='street2'>
    </div>

    <div class="address">
        <input type="text" name="house-name" value='house3'>
        <input type="text" name="street-no" value='street3'>
    </div>

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here `class="address"` wrapper will repeats many times. How can retrieve each element (house-name,street-no) values using Jquery

Tried as follows,

```
$.each($(".address"), function(key,value) { 

     hn = $(value).children("input[name=house-name]").val();
     console.log(n);
}
```

But fails :(

Expected Javascript output,

```
house1,street1
house2,street2
house3,street3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this variant instead:

```
$(".address").each(function() {
    var house = $(this).children("input[name='house-name']").val();
    var street = $(this).children("input[name='street-no']").val();
    console.log(house + "," + street);
});
```

Or (if you need) you can gather all the input values in the array:

```
$(".address").each(function() {
    var values = [];
    $(this).children("input").each(function() {
        values.push(this.value);
    });
    console.log(values.join(","));
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/PtNm5/

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each($(".address"), function(key,value) { 
     var hn = $(this).children('input[name="house-name"]').val(),
         sn = $(this).children('input[name="street-no"]').val();
     console.log(hn.concat(', ' + sn));
});
```

OR

```
 $.each($(".address"), function(key,value) { 
         var hn = $('input[name="house-name"]', this).val(),
             sn = $('input[name="street-no"]', this).val();
         console.log(hn.concat(', ' + sn));
    });
```

OR

```
$.each($('.address'), function() {
  var output = $('input[name="house-name"]', this).val().concat(', ' + $('input[name="street-no"]', this).val());
  console.log(output);
});
```